# LinkedList isn't taking input

Tags: java, linked-list

I seem to be having some problems with inserting values into a linked list. I am trying to create a program for the Josephus problem and I am suppose to take 3 numbers from the user. The first number is how many "people" there are, say its 4 you would have a list of 1,2,3,4. This is where I am stuck. Every time I enter in the 3 ints my program returns saying the List is empty and I can't figure out why. If anyone could help explain it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
         {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            long[] numbers = new long[3];
            LinkedList circle = new LinkedList();

            System.out.println("Please enter 3 numbers");

             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
               {
                  numbers[i] = input.nextLong();
               }
             for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0]; i++)
               {
                  circle.insertLink();
                  circle.move();
               }

             circle.getCurrent();
         }
```

**Link**

```
 class Link
   {
      public long dData;
      public Link next;

      public Link(long dd)
         {
            dData = dd;
         }

      public Link(int d, Link n)
         {
            this(d);
            next = n;
         }

      public void displayLink()
         {
            System.out.print(dData + " ");
         }        
   }
```

**Linked List**

```
class LinkedList
   {
      private Link current;
      private int id;

      public LinkedList()
      {
         current = null;
         id = 1;
      }

      public void move()
      {
         current = current.next;
      }

      public boolean isEmpty()
      {
         if(current == null)
         System.out.println("The List is empty");
         return current == null;
      }

      public Link getCurrent()
      {
         return current;
      }

      public void setCurrent(int id)
      {
         while(current.dData != id)
            move();
      }

      public Link getNext()
      {
         return current.next;
      }   

      public void insertLink()
      {
         if(!isEmpty())
            {
            Link newlink = new Link(id++, current.next);
            current.next = newlink;
            } 
            else 
            {
            Link newlink = new Link(id++);
            newlink.next = newlink;
            current = newlink;
            }
       }

       public Link deleteLink()
       {
         Link temp = current.next;
         if(current != current.next)
            current.next = current.next.next;
         else
            current = null;

         return temp; 
       }    
   }
```

Comment: does circle.getCurrent() returns null?

Comment: @noshusan here is a sample run  "Please enter 3 numbers|
5 4 3|
The List is empty"

Comment: @WCC96 that seem to be normal, the first time `isEmpty` is called (in `insertLink`) it will print that string, it doesn't mean that in the end the list is empty

Comment: @LorisSecuro hmm I see. How would I got about getting it to display all the numbers in the list? For example if I put in 5, how would I get it to display, 1 2 3 4 5. I'm kinda going step by step and making sure I have physical proof that what I want is getting done.

Answer (score 0):

when first time you call `insertLink()` methos you always will get `The List is empty` print. because at initialization the `current` variable of your linked list class is null. just remove `System.out.println("The List is empty");` from your code.

```
public boolean isEmpty()
  {
     return current == null;
  }
```

override `toString()` method to see your list

Comment: I keep getting "error: missing return statement" after deleting      System.out.println("The List is empty");

Answer (score 0):

You are taking three inputs from user and iterating with first element of numbers array, i think it should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
          {
             circle.insertLink();
             circle.move();
          }
```

And at the first time when you insert the link, `isEmpty()` method checks your `current` variable is `null` or not if it is then it print the `"The list is empty"`. so just remove that line.

```
System.out.println("The List is empty");
```

Comment: That's what i am trying to do. The 3 numbers submitted by the user do different things. The 1st number is the size of the list. The 2nd number is where the count starts. The 3rd is how many numbers it counts on the list and when it reaches that number, it deletes it.